# UIManager is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript

I have a class called UIManager which is going to handle UI changes across my project...

```
   /// <reference path="../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
    /// <reference path="../../typings/materialize-css/materialize-css.d.ts" />

    export class UIManager {

        constructor() {
        }

        public InitPanes(): void {
            $(".sideNav").sideNav({
                menuWidth:350
            });
        }

    }
```

I implement it in App.ts and run the solution, in the debug console I get the error "UIManager is undefined".

```
/// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="UIManager/UIManager.ts" />


import * as UI from "UIManager/UIManager";

class App {
    constructor() {
        let UIManager = new UI.UIManager();
        UIManager.InitPanes();
    }
}
$(document).ready(() => {
   let app = new App();
});
```

I'm new to TypeScript so all help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of error generally means that your HTML page is not loading the UIManager.js file correctly.
As you are using module syntax - to export a class (in UIManager.ts) and then import this class (in App.ts) - you will need to use either Require.js or System.js to dynamically load the UIManager.js file from your HTML page.

Comment: Thanks, I made a temporary work around. I am using bundles in ASP.NET so I just changed the order the file was being loaded in. Maybe implementing requirejs or systemjs will be handy.